# Pure CSS Slider

Tags: html, css, slider

So I'm getting acquainted with css3 and I've been trying to find a purely css slider. I finally found one that is exactly as I was looking for on code pen but for some reason when I try the code in localhost or jsfiddle it doesn't work. There is no external files that its accessing as far as I can tell in codepen and there is no jQuery needed. Below I've linked the (working) codepen and jsfiddle. Any ideas why it wont work elsewhere?

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/CoadyAu/pen/IyihA)**

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxwk88n6/)**

html

```
<div class="slider">
  <img class='photo'  src="http://i.imgur.com/zMGSiyl.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://i.imgur.com/soQhb13.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://i.imgur.com/39yOaYB.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://i.imgur.com/tnctKD4.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

css

```
body{background:#000;}

.slider{
  margin:50px auto;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;

}
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;
  width:100%;

}
@keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 

img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:12s;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works perfectly, please check: **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vxwk88n6/6/)**. The syntax for the CSS3 animations and the keyframes which was being used in the code was the standard syntax, for e.g. `animation:round 16s infinite;`, `@keyframes round{ 25%{opacity:1;} 40%{opacity:0;} }` and `img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}`.

You should instead use `` -webkit-animation:round 16s infinite;`, `@-webkit-keyframes round{ 25%{opacity:1;} 40%{opacity:0;} } ` and `img:nth-child(4){-webkit-animation-delay:0s;} `` so that it's browser compatible.

More information on this is available over [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.slider {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.photo {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: round 16s infinite;
  -o-animation: round 16s infinite;
  animation: round 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
img:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
}
img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/zMGSiyl.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/soQhb13.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/39yOaYB.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/tnctKD4.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can try to answer this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518770/anchor-tag-click-not-working-in-css-slider

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use vendor specific `keyframes`. Codepen is clever and is overcompensating in this instance.

```
@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

More info http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/