# Anchor tag click not working in CSS slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I would like to use the following CSS slider in my project

http://jsfiddle.net/63w9jnqq/1/

It does not using any JavaScript or jQuery. When I clicking on the link from any slide other than the **'slide 5'** takes me back to the first **'slide 5'** instead of opening a new tab. It is CSS heavy code, I have no idea about how to fix it. I have no problem to use extra jQuery or JavaScript to fix this issue.

I tried the following jQuery to stop click action, it does not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide-gfx a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: no way, It work only with FireFox and it won't open a new tab when you click on any link on the slider number 2 ( slider 2 ), Can you check once again ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Trust me. I am using Chrome! `:)`

Comment: Okay, may be I am not understanding the issue.

Comment: I can't even see the slider in my chrome, but able to see in incognito mode

Comment: I can see the issue in my Chromium browser...not sure about the fix though

Comment: Slider working perfectly in Firefox, but click event not open a new tab

Comment: Ah... Man, looks like a caching issue to me. @uncivilized

Comment: @PraveenKumar , I don't know which css code is responsible to show the next slider. if we can find that code , then let's fix it - i hope

Comment: This is so weird... when you click for instance somewhere in the HTML, JS, or CSS editing windows in the jsfiddle, the slider goes back to `Slider 5` as well. Even weirder, I have my Chrome DevTools open, and *in DevTools* I click the *Clear console* button, and even then it goes back to `Slider 5`!

Comment: `$(document).on("click","*",function(e){console.log(e.target);});` will not output anything when you click on a link on any of the slides other than `Slider 5`! *(Changing `e.target` to `this` will still output nothing)*

Comment: @myfunkyside Click issue only in the case of anchor tag with href attribute. Issue is related with 'href' attribute

Answer (score 0):

### :focus state

The cause of this issue is down to the fact that the slideshow is relying on the `:focus` handling of CSS to remember state. This is a very temporary handler, which is lost whenever a new element is focused. I built the slideshow more for non-interactive elements, just to demo visual work — this works fine with `:focus`

The slideshow reverts back to slide 5 (or the end slide) when none of the slides are focused. This was fine for my needs, but obviously not for your use-case. This is occurring when you focus on your `<a href="" />` elements.

#### Limitations of css

Unfortunately there is no way to match (in current CSS) up to a parent from a focused child — at least not that I am aware of. This would solve the issue with pure CSS. You can obviously match downwards (i.e. `parent:focus .child`), but that doesn't help. You can employ the [The checkbox/radio hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) which I did consider at the time, or you can switch to using a different way of "remembering state".

### :target state

The CSS in the original demo was already tailored to also support `:target` as an alternative, so you can patch current functionality with a small bit of JS. I wouldn't want to rely on this across older browsers however — but then again, older browsers would probably find it hard to cope with this system anyway.

#### Snippet and fiddle

This patch listens for the `:focus` event, and sets the fragment in the URL to match the id of the slide. This means that the CSS then switches to listening to the `:target` selectors instead, which should keep the right slide selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/63w9jnqq/4/

```
$('.slide').on('focus',function(e){
  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

### Recommendation

Going forward, I'd suggest perhaps looking at more recent methods for implementing CSS. As I'm sure there are a lot of new improvements that could be used to extend the system — something I haven't had time for of late. There may even be handling to integrate touch-style events to make things more naturally mobile friendly, although perhaps that is just wishful thinking.

At the end of the day, even though there is a lot of CSS in this solution, it is best to try and understand every part of the code you use in your projects — as that helps to debug situations you might find yourself in. This issue is mentioned in the original post here, and the solution using `:target` is employed to handle the "sub nav" links:

[Implement a CSS-only slideshow / carousel with next and previous buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647389)